# Copying work items from Visual Studio Online (TFS) and getting HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-team-services

I want to copy work items from TFS/Visual Studio Online by selecting them and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or right-click, copy, and get the HTML. However Visual Studio Online overrides the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and right-click, and doesn't let me copy the HTML so I can paste in elsewhere and retain the formatting.

Is there anyway to disable this behaviour and do a normal copy?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is the Email selected work items. That will give you a list with work item links in a table. It won't be the same as what you see in the web page screenshot, but it is better than what Ctrl-c gives you. Even if it didn't override Ctrl-c I don't think you'd get the representation you'd want. At some point, I do hope to get nicer formatting in the email work items dialog.

Comment: Buck we already had been doing the email and paste. I think without the override it would work? Cos every other site seems to work like that as long as it isn't using flash, if you do the ctrl + C in chrome?

Comment: I talked to a dev who works on it, and he reminded me that without overriding ctrl-c you wouldn't be able to copy the off screen work items. Regardless, I've asked that we look at how we can improve this in the future. The text we put on the clipboard isn't nearly as useful as it could be.

Comment: I think if we could share it readonly with customers via a public URL or copy it as is, either way would solve the issue. You could still copy all the items if you zoom way out, or copy the first ten then the next 10, so that developer is just making excuses like we all do.